# ¿Como cambiar dinamicamente la propiedad forecolor de un style en jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

hola tengo un reporte el cual se conecta a una BD entre sus campos trae el codigo del color en hexadecimal. Y de acuerdo a cierta condicion el texto debe aplicar el color que le corresponda.

```
<style name="miestilo">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{identificacion}.equals("1102")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#008000" backcolor="#F60404"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

el color esta asociado a un campo que viene de la base de datos.
Gracias